# UserNamePasswordValidator: When DI and Framework collide

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, autofac

I am building a custom UserNamePasswordValidator for a WCF service.  I am wiring up the service with Autofac + WCF/multitenant, all fitting neatly together.  However I'm not sure what strategy to use to wire/implement this authentication class.

Ideally, I would start with

```
public class MyValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator {
    public MyValidator(Func<Owned<IMyUserService>> userservicefactory) {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, this isn't strictly possible because of the way that a UserNamePasswordValidator is consumed by WCF (the only option appears to be parameterless constructor).

So, questions:

1. Am I correct or is there some WCF config voodoo with which a UserNamePasswordValidator *factory* can be configured?
2. If "no", what is the most "DI-correct" fallback strategy that can be used in this scenario?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I configured the service host in code at startup or within a custom ServiceHostFactory.

From the XML configuration, I removed

```
<userNameAuthentication 
          userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
          customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Common.MyCustomUsernamePasswordValidator, Common"/ -->
```

And since I configured my container prior to hosting:

```
var auth = host.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication;
auth.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
auth.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = container.Resolve<Common.MyCustomUsernamePasswordValidator>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at UserNameSecurityTokenAuthenticator, you can do the validation in this class and skip the UsernamepasswordValidator.

And you can implement your own ServiceCredentialsSecurityTokenManager, which you can determine how to create the authenticator.

Comment: Thanks Jack.  That's further down the rabbit hole than I needed or wanted to travel, but +1 for pointing me in the right direction.