# How to inject dependencies into a custom UserNamePasswordValidator in WCF using Ninject?

Tags: c#, wcf, ninject

I'm using a UserNamePasswordValidator in WCF with Ninject for my dependency injection, but Ninject  cannot inject my container into the class.

```
class MyUserNamePassValidator : System.IdentityModel.Selectors.UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    private MyService _myService;        

    public MyUserNamePassValidator(MyService myService)
    {
        this._myService = myService;
    } 

    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
         this._myService.Login(userName, password); // this._myService is null
    }
}
```

Comment: I used a factory to create an instance of a class that implements the methods needed. WCF creates this class, so you can't control the creation of it.

Comment: maybe this documentation can give you some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/wcf/5509/how-to-use-a-dependency-injection-container-with-a-wcf-service/19594/how-to-configure-a-wcf-service-to-use-a-dependency-injection-container-castle-w#t=201608261641351721511

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately WCF will not allow you tricking into validator creation process, e.g. by passing factory instead of type as ServiceHost would.
Here is a part of WCF sources (`UserNameServiceElement` class) that makes it clear:

```
  Type type = Type.GetType(this.CustomUserNamePasswordValidatorType, true);
  if (!typeof (UserNamePasswordValidator).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    throw DiagnosticUtility.ExceptionUtility.ThrowHelperError((Exception) new ConfigurationErrorsException(System.ServiceModel.SR.GetString("ConfigInvalidUserNamePasswordValidatorType", (object) this.CustomUserNamePasswordValidatorType, (object) typeof (UserNamePasswordValidator).ToString())));
  userName.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = (UserNamePasswordValidator) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

There are 2 workarounds I can see:

- Create validator programmatically, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6761284/63867
- Use Service Locator pattern instead of Dependency Injection one

Answer (score -1):

In short, you don't need Ninject or any other similar, because .NET Framework has built-in features for this.

Please read

[Authentication and Authorization with ASP.NET Identity 2.0 for WCF Services](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/802435/Authentication-and-Authorization-with-ASP-NET-Iden)

Please node, though the article talks about Identity 2.0, you will find you might not need it if you read the article carefully. You will know how to inject your validator through some simple change in the config file.

Comment: But I WANT to use Ninject for some very good reason, and I assume the OP too. So, this answer is useless, since it is just an advertisment for a confusing code project article.